# When I set up nodejs on cpanel, it says it can't allocate memory

Tags: node.js, cpanel

When I run the command

```
npm run dev
```

on the cpanel terminal to configure the application, I get an error message "vite v5.0.10 building for production...
node:internal/process/promises:289
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

[RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: Cannot allocate Wasm memory for new instance]"

Is there any way to help me set up the memory

Answer (score 0):

When a cPanel user exceeds the PMEM limit in the LVE settings they will be restricted from allocating more memory to their processes. You can contact with your hosting company .